# axios cors issue, when ajax get data

Tags: php, ajax, axios

I need to get data from :

> https://huaris.script-studio.pl/assets/php/chart1.php

Also i have to pass key and value as dataLimit, witch generate exactly amount of data, for example dataLimit:2 generate 2 last rows.
The thing is:
ajax code:

```
post_data = {
 dataLimit:7
},      
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain:true,
    data: post_data,
    url: "https://huaris.script-studio.pl/assets/php/chart1.php",
    beforeSend: function() {
           console.log(post_data)
    },
    success: function (data) {
console.log(data)}
  })
```

Witch working:

> Request URL: https://huaris.script-studio.pl/assets/php/chart1.php
>   Request Method: POST Status Code: 200  Remote Address:
>   46.242.247.49:443 Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

but axios:

> Request URL: https://huaris.script-studio.pl/assets/php/chart1.php
>   Request Method: OPTIONS Status Code: 200  Remote Address:
>   46.242.247.49:443 Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

axios code look like that: 
[image]

And offcorse CORSE error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://huaris.script-studio.pl/assets/php/chart1.php' from origin
>   'https://confident-jones-a00a99.netlify.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Also, if i turn off cors with crome extension, i get all records, like dataLimit not working, but ajax call do the job with expected output.

Where is a issue? we schould add something more to chart1.php script?? or what?